# how can I show ldap account on lightdm xfce

Tags: xfce, lightdm, ldap

I got another problem with ldap account on lightdm greeter. Lightdm greeter could not list ldap user. Therefore, After logging in with LDAP account, I restarted the computer, the LDAP account was not displayed on lightdm greeter. I had to type user/pass again for logging with the ldap account. Show how can I show ldap account on lightdm greeter? Thanks for any help!

Comment: To clarify, you would like to see a list of accounts on your LightDM greeter that have successfully signed in via LDAP, correct?

Comment: FYI:  Xubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Xfce (*not Xubuntu*).

Comment: Xubuntu 18.04 has reached EOL , Questions about EOL releases are no longer supported. Consider upgrading to latest version or latest LTS version